# jQuery - render multiple div elements w/slideToggle feature

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

In the index page of my ASP MVC 3 view I have a collection object that may have as many as 50 or so elements. To keep the index clean for the user, I am trying to use the jQuery `.slideToggle` feature when the collection contains more than 5 items.

However, I'm currently doing this in `$(document).ready` and, since I gave the `<div>` elements the same name, when you click on one, they all expand or collapse.

I'm brand new to jQuery, so I'm wondering what the best way to accomplish this goal would be and if, this method is a good way to go, how to allow only item I've click on the collapse/expand.

Here is the jQuery code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hidden").hide();
        $(".expand").click(function () {
            $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");

            if ($(".expand").html() == "[+] Expand") {
                $(".expand").html("[-] Collapse");
            } else {
                $(".expand").html("[+] Expand");
            }
        });
    });
```

and here are the `<div>`'s. Since this is the index page, these are in a `foreach` loop and thus repeated for every record (thus each one is given the same name).

```
        @if (item.BankListAgentId.Count > 5)
        {
            <div class="expand">[+] Expand</div>
            <div class="hidden">
                @foreach (var thing in item.BankListAgentId)
                {
                    string value = thing.FixedOrVariable.Trim();
                    if (value.Equals("F"))
                    {
                        var agentId = thing.AgentId.Trim();
                        var link = ViewBag.Periscope + agentId;
                        <a href="@link" target="_blank">@thing.StateCode: @agentId</a>
                        <br />                     
                    }
                }                
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend changing your jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hidden").hide();
    $(".expand").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");

        if ($(this).html() == "[+] Expand") {
            $(this).html("[-] Collapse");
        } else {
            $(this).html("[+] Expand");
        }
    });
});
```

That way you'll only target the `.hidden` element that's next to the `.expand` you clicked, also by using `this` instead of `.expand` you'll only target the clicked element...

Comment: Hey no problem, I'm glad it did :)